Can this ceiling light box be used to mount a ceiling fan?
I'd like to replace some of the existing light fixtures in my home with ceiling fans with a light. It looks like this box is attached to a joist but I don't see any reference weight limit like I have on other boxes that I know can be used for a ceiling fan. Can I use this box or can I replace it with making other modifications to the ceiling?


If not listed/marked for fan use, then better to get one that is listed/marked for fans.

That's a fan rated box.  The longer screws are to mount the fan support.

the long  screws are due to it being mounted too far behind (above) the surface of the ceiling.

But the box itself is mounted with 3 screws to a bracket.  If you unscrew those and drop the box out, what does the bracket look like?
